# Safari cannot open page because iPhone is not connected to Internet

Tags: iphone, wifi, cellular-data, mobile-safari

I recently started getting this message *"Safari cannot open page because iPhone is not connected to Internet"*  whenever I leave a Wi-Fi zone.

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 2):

You need to turn off WiFi before you leave the coverage area (or more precisely - before you reach the point where WiFi is still "connected" but not viable.)

In iOS 9 there will be a system setting to allow cellular data to take over sooner, but on iOS 8 and less, your device will throw errors when WiFi fails you and before the radio disconnects from WiFi.

Manually disconnect or control your location so that you don't try to use the internet when WiFi isn't viable.

Answer (score 2):

If you're on an iPhone or iPad go to Settings then Cellular and swipe down to make sure you haven't accidentally toggled the switch off for Safari to access the internet.

Comment: Thank you very much. Safari was turned off. Did the settings then cellular, swiped down and safari was the only app turned off. Yea, back in action.